# BizTalk 2010 not adding a project type to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, biztalk

I am setting up a BizTalk server on a new VM and I install BizTalk 2010 Host Integration Developer Ed. but it does not add the project type to VS 2012!!! This is a completely fresh install, and VS was installed first. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Microsoft. BizTalk 2010 projects can not be opened from Visual Studio 2012:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx#project

BizTalk 2010    You can’t open the project in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Are you licensed for Visual Studio 2010? Or was there something specific in 2012 you needed? I haven't tried it, but I think you can build helper classes in 2012 and use them, but it won't support features of 2012 from say Expression shapes... But I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah I have access to all the VS editions... I'm trying to configure everything to work on the latest and greatest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use biztalk 2013 beta, if you need development in VS 2012.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalk_server_team_blog/archive/2012/11/06/announcing-biztalk-server-2013-beta.aspx